# What's the shortest way to get the length/dimension of a table in KDB?

Tags: kdb

Currently I'm doing a `select count` which seems like a difficult way of achieving it.

Is there a way a simple length/size/dimension operator?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `count` with the table name is valid.

```
q)count trades
2000
```

This is a lot faster than using the virtual column `i` as information on the table count is stored in the header of the flat file.

```
q)\t:10000000 select count i from trades
9910
q)\t:10000000 count trades
592
```